# Trying to host multiple customer domains on RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to allow the hosting of multiple customers domains on a single ruby on rails web application similar to shopify. SSL cert will be needed so multiple IP's will be required. How should I go about doing this? Should I create a feature to create new VirtualHosts in Apache for each domain?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of configuring Rails to use domains as part of `config/routes.rb`, but one way I used recently for HTTP was to apply the rewrite as Rack middleware, inserting the code as an initializer using the [rack-rewrite](http://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) gem for convenience, and pointing to a namespace. I imagine you could use a similar starting point for HTTPS.

Add to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rack-rewrite'
```

Add as an initializer, loading before anything that requires it, such as `config/initializers/0_rack_rewrite.rb`:

```
Unshopify::Application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  rewrite %r{.*}, "/unshopify$&", :not => %r{/assets.*}, :host => "unshopify.example.com"
end
```

Add to `config/routes.rb`:

```
namespace :unshopify, :path => 'unshopify' do
  resource :statics, :only => [:home]

  root :to => 'statics#home'
end
```

The `:path` is not needed if it is the same as the default for the namespace.

You could, of course, point the rewrites to the same namespace, or no namespace at all, and then do logic based on some other method. The [rack-rewrite](http://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) documentation describes all sorts of fun.